# ¿Cómo modifico un txt utilizando getline?

Tags: c++, login

necesito ayuda con respecto a este problema, la funcion modificar la invoco desde un void, pero no me modifica, la función crear archivo, leer, incluso la funcion de buscar archivo me funciona, pero esta no encuentro la manera de hacer que resulte.

Cambie de lugar el remove y el rename, por que el archivo auxiliar se creaba pero no se renombra y no se borra que es lo quede debería hacer.

Las variables de archivos las declare de forma global.

```
void modificarp(ifstream &Lec)
    {
        system("cls");
        string nomaux;
        string mcorreo;
        string mcargo;
        string mmaquina;
        string mnivel;
        string msueldo;
        bool encontrado = false;
        Lec.open("Empleados.txt",ios::in);
        ofstream aux("auxiliar.txt",ios::out);
        if (Lec.is_open())
        {
            cout<<"Maquina---:";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin,mmaquina);
            getline(Lec, nomuser,'\n'); 
            while(!Lec.eof())
            {
                getline(Lec, direc,'\n');   
                getline(Lec, ced,'\n'); 
                getline(Lec, cel,'\n'); 
                getline(Lec, tel,'\n'); 
                getline(Lec, cargo,'\n');   
                getline(Lec, edad,'\n');    
                getline(Lec, sex,'\n'); 
                getline(Lec, turno,'\n');   
                getline(Lec, correo,'\n');  
                getline(Lec, sueldoini,'\n');
                getline(Lec, maquina,'\n');     
                getline(Lec, clave,'\n');   
                getline(Lec, tuser,'\n');
                if (maquina==mmaquina)
                {
                    cout<<"Nuevo Nombre---:";
                    cin.ignore();
                    getline(cin, nomaux);   
aux<<nomaux<<'\n'<<direc<<'\n'<<ced<<'\n'<<cel<<'\n'<<tel<<'\n'<<cargo<<'\n'<<edad<<'\n'<<sex<<'\n'<<turno<<'\n'<<correo<<'\n'<<sueldoini<<'\n'<<maquina<<'\n'<<clave<<'\n'<<tuser<<endl;
                    Lec.close();
                    aux.close();
                    remove("Empleados.txt");
                    rename("auxiliar.txt","Empleados.txt");         
                }
                else
                {
                    aux<<nomuser<<'\n'<<direc<<'\n'<<ced<<'\n'<<cel<<'\n'<<tel<<'\n'<<cargo<<'\n'<<edad<<'\n'<<sex<<'\n'<<turno<<'\n'<<correo<<'\n'<<sueldoini<<'\n'<<maquina<<'\n'<<clave<<'\n'<<tuser<<endl;
                }
                    getline(Lec, nomuser,'\n'); 
            }
        }
        else
        cout<<"ERROR"<<s;
        system ("pause");
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que pretendes exactamente?  ¿Qué tiene que ver `GetLine` con `rename`? ¿En qué momento escribes en `aux`? ¿Dónde están declaradas todas las variables que faltan por declarar?

Comment: Lo que quiero es, que luego de ingresar datos en un formulario, llamar a un metodo que lo pueda modificar, el rename no me funciona ni el remove, por eso empece a moverlo pro que puede que lo este usando mal, todas las variables esrtan declaradas de manera global, justo debajo del namespace

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Cómo modifico un txt utilizando getline?

No lo haces. *Get* (obtener) es para leer, no para escribir. Por lo que deduzco de la manera en que usas los flujos de datos de archivo tienes un lío conceptual con esos términos.

Los objetos `ifstream` y `ofstream` son flujos de Entrada y Salida de datos a archivo respectivamente:

- `ifstream` ***I**nput **F**ile **STREAM***: flujo (stream) de entrada (input) de datos a archivo (file).
- `ofstream` ***O**utput **F**ile **STREAM***: flujo (stream) de salida (output) de datos a archivo (file).

Dado que están pre-configurados para entrada o salida, no necesitas especificarlo al abrir:

```
Lec.open("Empleados.txt",ios::in);
//                       ^^^^^^^ <--- Innecesario, ya es de lectura.
ofstream aux("auxiliar.txt",ios::out);
//                          ^^^^^^^^ <--- Innecesario, ya es de escritura.
```

Los archivos en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) funcionan de manera similar a un *búfer de datos*, para modificar un dato debes sobrescribir el espacio que ocupa, de manera que si tienes un archivo con los siguientes datos:

`datos.txt`

```
Hola
Adiós
```

En memoria estará representado como:

```
| 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| H| o| l| a|\n| A| d| i| ó| s|
```

Si quieres modificar el dato `Hola` por `Glückwunsch` lo que sucederá es lo siguiente:

```
| 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|10|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| G| l| ü| c| k| w| u| n| s| c| h|
```

No sólo se sobrescribe el dato posterior al dato que estabas modificando, si no que has superado el espacio que originalmente tenías asignado. Así que para modificar datos en un archivo, lo más fácil es:

1. Leer todos los datos desde archivo a memoria.
2. Modificar los datos en memoria.
3. Reescribir el archivo completo desde memoria a archivo.